# XSLT string join error

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join(PRICES//SELL_PRICE_ID,'@'),'dates',string- join(PRICES//PRICE_DATE, '@'))"/>
```

I am receiving the next error:
An error occurred updating the resource:
An error occurred compiling the XSLT template: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: string-join.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ if you want to use that function as [it was introduced in 2007 in XSLT/XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string-join) and the XSLT processor in the Oracle/Sun JRE only supports XSLT 1.0 from 1999.