# XSLT - get value of all nodes with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the next XML:

```
<OPTION>
  <PRICES>
     <PRICE>
        <PRICE_DATE>25 Nov 2014</PRICE_DATE>
     </PRICE>
     <PRICE>
         <PRICE_DATE>26 Nov 2014</PRICE_DATE>
      </PRICE>
  </PRICES>
 </OPTION>
```

In my XSLT I need the value of all PRICE_DATE (25 Nov 2014 and 26 Nov 2014 ).

```
      <xsl:value-of select="PRICES//PRICE_DATE"/>
```

but the returning value is only the 25 Nov 2014 .

How to get the values of the all nodes with the same name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT string join error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088701/xslt-string-join-error)

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime and make sure your stylesheet has `version="2.0"` as in that case you should get both values or with an XSLT 1.0 processor you need to use `<xsl:for-each select="PRICES//PRICE_DATE"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:for-each>` respectively `<xsl:apply-templates select="PRICES//PRICE_DATA"/>` to make sure all selected nodes are processed and output. With XSLT 1.0 the `xsl:value-of` element only outputs the string value of the first selected node.